# Unable to fix the logic in the slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, swiper.js

I've create a slider which works with dynamic data. What I'm trying to achieve is when I click on the slides it should select that slide and the rest should rotate in order in the container. So I was able to achieve this only with the button but I'm having problem having the onclick functionality on the slides.

```js
const slideContainer = document.querySelector('.slide');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next');
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prev');
fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // Create HTML elements based on the fetched data

    data.forEach(country => {
      const item = document.createElement('div');
      item.classList.add('item');

      // Customize the content based on your data structure
      item.innerHTML = `
          <div class="item-wrapper">
              <img src="${country.flags.svg}" alt="${country.name.common}">
              <div class="content">
                  <div class="sub-name">${country.name.common}</div>
                  <div class="name">${country.region}</div>
                  <button>See More</button>
                  <div class="des">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, eum!</div>
                  <div class="icon-wrapper">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="svg-icons">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M17.593 3.322c1.1.128 1.907 1.077 1.907 2.185V21L12 17.25 4.5 21V5.507c0-1.108.806-2.057 1.907-2.185a48.507 48.507 0 0 1 11.186 0Z" />
                      </svg>
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="svg-icons">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M21 8.25c0-2.485-2.099-4.5-4.688-4.5-1.935 0-3.597 1.126-4.312 2.733-.715-1.607-2.377-2.733-4.313-2.733C5.1 3.75 3 5.765 3 8.25c0 7.22 9 12 9 12s9-4.78 9-12Z" />
                      </svg>
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="svg-icons">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M7.217 10.907a2.25 2.25 0 1 0 0 2.186m0-2.186c.18.324.283.696.283 1.093s-.103.77-.283 1.093m0-2.186 9.566-5.314m-9.566 7.5 9.566 5.314m0 0a2.25 2.25 0 1 0 3.935 2.186 2.25 2.25 0 0 0-3.935-2.186Zm0-12.814a2.25 2.25 0 1 0 3.933-2.185 2.25 2.25 0 0 0-3.933 2.185Z" />
                      </svg>

                </div>
                <button class="view-btn">
                    <span>ver pedra</span>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" >
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="m4.5 19.5 15-15m0 0H8.25m11.25 0v11.25" />
                      </svg>
                      </button>
              </div>
              <p class="unfocus-names">${country.region}</p>
          </div>
                    `;

      // Append the item to the slide container
      slideContainer.appendChild(item);
    });
  })
  .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));



nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
  slideContainer.appendChild(items[0]);
});

prevBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
  slideContainer.prepend(items[items.length - 1]);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
  body {
    font-size: 14px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  .slide,
  .prev,
  .next {
    display: none;
  }
  .swiper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 50px;
  }
  .swiper-slide {
    height: 100% !important;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .icon-wrapper {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    gap: 18px;
  }
  .svg-icons {
    width: 24px;
  }
  .img-div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
  }
  .swiper-slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
  }
  .content {
    font-family: system-ui;
  }
  .navigation {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    bottom: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
  }
  .navigation>* {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  .navigation svg {
    width: 13px;
  }
  .content .sub-name {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #838282;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .content .name {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .content button {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #b1b0b0;
    color: #7d7d7d;
  }
  .content .des {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .view-btn {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
  }
  .view-btn svg {
    width: 14px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
  body {
    background: #eaeaea;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .container {
    transform: translate(-85%, -5%);
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 120px;
  }
  .container .slide .item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 80%;
    transform: translate(290%, -50%);
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  .container .slide .item .item-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: relative;
  }
  .container .slide .item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
  }
  .slide .item:nth-child(1),
  .slide .item:nth-child(2) {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .slide .item:nth-child(1) .item-wrapper p,
  .slide .item:nth-child(2) .item-wrapper p {
    display: none;
  }
  .slide .item .item-wrapper p {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .slide .item:nth-child(3) {
    left: 150%;
  }
  .slide .item:nth-child(4) {
    left: calc(150% + 120px);
  }
  .slide .item:nth-child(5) {
    left: calc(150% + 240px);
  }
  /* here n = 0, 1, 2, 3,... */
  .slide .item:nth-child(n + 6) {
    left: calc(150% + 360px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .item .content {
    transform: translateZ(-10px);
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    right: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    font-family: system-ui;
    display: none;
    animation: animate 1s ease-in-out 1 forwards;
  }
  .slide .item:nth-child(2) .content {
    display: block;
  }
  .content .sub-name {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: semibold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .content .name {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .content .des {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  .content button {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(216, 216, 216);
    color: #ababab;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  @keyframes animate {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
    30% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 100;
      transform: translate(650px);
    }
  }
  .icon-wrapper {
    margin: 30px auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
  }
  .svg-icons {
    width: 28px;
  }
  .button {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
  }
  .button button {
    width: 40px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  .button button:hover {
    background: #ababab;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .view-btn {
    margin-top: 70px;
    border-color: black !important;
    color: black !important;
    width: 150px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .view-btn svg {
    width: 12px;
  }
  .swiper {
    display: none;
  }
  .prev-btn,
  .next-btn {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="slide">

  </div>

  <div class="button">
    <button class="prev"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
    <button class="next"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
  </div>

</div>
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve
[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iYWYBr7AQ9dYOl_ksKXr_-_Zvkbd8ywa/view?usp=sharing)

This is what I've achieved
[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r47Drh7Lmu0B2cpdGKl0oyy2nz07GPvM/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, given your current code, is to add a click handler on every `item` Element, calculate the current index, and `Element.append()` all the subset of that array of items.

Add the following near the end of your code:

```js
// items click
slideContainer.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  const item = evt.target.closest(".item");
  if (!item) return;
  const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')];
  const idx = items.indexOf(item);
  slideContainer.append(...items.slice(0, idx - 1));
});
```

The animation for the other thumbnails will be hard to achieve with the current CSS and JS logic. The best would be to create an "endless slider" where on item click you animate the items in respect the the current index.

[Demo on jsBin.com](https://jsbin.com/huwefiw/edit?js,output)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked like a charm.
I have another concer if you can help, right now there are two divs that are overlaping on each other on left so that the white background shouldnt be visible. In the video which I'm trying to achieve  its not like that, the div thats being pushed to the back of the container, is sliding to the left while the new div is sliding in . How do I achieve that.
This is what I achieved after removing the two divs overlapping each other.
[Result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LsWJrUAYnkGQTol23wVKZLMU6X89i9jH/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @DawoodTrumboo you can achieve that by creating and endless slider. Your code I'm afraid does not allows currently for such an implementation - and a response that covers that extra request would go outside of the scope of the asked question + provided sample. Basically it would be an entire rewrite of your logic (not only JS, but also CSS and HTML).

Comment: Alright, thats understandable. In your solution there is some issue, when we click on the 2nd or 3rd slide, both the divs on the left disappears and then the clicked div slides in. is there a fix? or do I've to come up with the whole new logic for the slider ?

Comment: @DawoodTrumboo let me see as soon as possible. From what I can see I guess only CSS. but let me get to my machine.

Comment: @DawoodTrumboo yes. I'm afraid so. Currently you're appending the underlying (0th) element to the end of the items in order to animate the next (index 2) on top of the currently active (index 1). If you wanted to animate by two or three the logic becomes overly complicated - specially if you want to maintain the returned order (original sequence) of the items.

Comment: one solution woujld be to always keep the currently active item as a temporary clone/placeholder, but anyways the animation of all the other elements would become a snappy mess (i.e: with the third thumbnail not animation into view). The best thing, I repeat, would be to create an ""endless slider" with the only difference that the currently active index item has those special *scaled-in* styles.